# Changing the contents of an href link

Tags: javascript, href

The following code is a test piece.  Normally the href in the Link would point to "http://www.google.com/", but the attr should change it to reference "http://maps.google.com"  BUT, the reference is not changing.  Can anyone tell me why it is not working?  Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a#changeme").attr('href', 
'http:\/\/maps.google.com/');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
<p>Link to <a href="http://www.google.com/" 
id="changeme">Google</a>
in the content...</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not just use `#changeme` as your selector?  ID selectors are the fastest.  Selectors run backwards -- so it finds #changeme first and then filters out only the anchors....but why do that if you have a unique ID?

Comment: Why use `text/javascript`? All modern-day browsers interpret script tags without the `type` attribute to be Javascript. This is a very old technique.

Answer (score 3):

1. jQuery is not loaded.
2. If it was, you would have to wrap it in a [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.
3. This can be done without jQuery.

Code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("changeme").href = 'http://maps.google.com/';
};
```

The `onload` handler is not exactely equal to the DOMContentLoaded handler, but it has a better support, and may be preferred here. Alternatively, you can move the `<srcipt>` block to the end of the `<body>`, and then use the method without any `onload` handlers:

```
<body>
<div class="content">
<p>Link to <a href="http://www.google.com/" id="changeme">Google</a>
in the content...</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // This code is placed after the element, so the reference does exist now.
  // In the head, the same code will throw an error, because the body doesn't
  // even exist.
  document.getElementById("changeme").href = 'http://maps.google.com/';
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: OK.  So now to the crux of my problem.  The reference I need to change is the XXX bit in the follwoing script.

Comment: Soory forgot the script, but I have since tried what you suggest and I think it has solved my problem.  Need to thoroughly check it though.  So thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The script is in the header so it's executed before the other content has been loaded (if jQuery is even active, seeing no reference to it). You should put it in a function and then call it later on (e.g. through `onload` or a timer). I could as well think of a security feature in the browser, to keep sites from manipulating links right before you click on them.

Comment: Thanks yes I understand that now.  What is the security feature though?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one, but e.g. you could have a link saying "http://www.google.com/" in the status bar, but the second you click it's set to "http://www-google-com.fake-site.com/". But as mentioned, it's more likely due to the way you wrote the script (outside a function).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the correct jQuery way to do this (using the document ready).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#changeme").attr('href', 'http:\/\/maps.google.com/');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
<p>Link to <a id="changeme" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
in the content<a href="test">test</a>...</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```